# Parse a tab delimited file and create another text file with only one column as output using PHP

Tags: php, parsing

I need to read a text file(input.txt) with '\t' delimiter and only display one column as output in another text file(output.txt).
I'm very new to this and hoping for some solutions.

`input.txt` file looks something like this:

```
user1 email1 group1
user2 email2 group2
user3 email3 group3 and so on
```

I managed to find the following code to read the file and print array but wasn't sure how to write only one column to `output.txt` file.

```
$fp = fopen('input.txt', 'r');

while ( !feof($fp) )
{
    $line = fgets($fp);

    $data_txt = str_getcsv($line, "\t");
    print_r($data_txt);
    exit;
}                              

fclose($fp);
```

which gives me a result in array:

```
array (
  0 => 'user1',
  1 => 'email1',
  2 => 'group1',
)array (
  0 => 'user2',
  1 => 'email2',
  2 => 'group2',
)array (
  0 => 'user3',
  1 => 'email3',
  2 => 'group3',
)
```

Now, how do i push **just** the email column into a output.txt file? Any thoughts?

Expected Output in output.txt is something like:

```
email1
email2
email3 and so on
```

I looked at other similar questions for the past 2 days but couldn't find a proper answer to write output into a new text file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of `print_r()` and `exit`, just write the email into an array or a file.

Comment: Thanks! The marked answer does it in a much simpler way.

Comment: The marked answer does exactly what I said :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are many ways to achieve this. I would suggest you to open a file pointer of the output file and write to this file line by line whenever you read a new line and just pick the 2nd index from the array of strings you just read.

```
<?php

$fp = fopen('input.txt', 'r');
$outputFP = fopen('output.txt', 'w+');

while (!feof($fp) ){
    $line = explode("\t",fgets($fp));
    fwrite($outputFP, $line[1] . PHP_EOL);
}                              

fclose($fp);
fclose($outputFP);
```

Comment: This works! Thanks!
A lot simpler than modifying my code.

Comment: One more thing, What do i change in this code to get a row instead of a column?
Something like user1 email1 group1.

Comment: @Karg `$line` is the array that has all 3 values.

Comment: Yes - but i tried a few different variations to get just the one row and failed at each. Could you help!?

Comment: @karg You would need to elaborate that. It's better if you ask a new question.